# Formik Form is not submitting

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, chakra-ui

So I've tried everything in order to submit the following form.

For some context, FormikForm is the normal Form that Formik gives you. I am using Chakra-UI. I am trying to send the initial values, as well as the tags below, which are all defined in their own state. When submitting, I create an object in the onSubmitForm function in which I add all the values passed in the onSubmitForm(values) below, as well as the value of the states for the tags.

```
 <Box mt={100} textAlign="center">
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        companyName: "",
        ruc: "",
        rucAgain: "",
        password: "",
        passwordAgain: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
      }}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        alert("submitted");
        onSubmitForm(values);
      }}
    >
      {(props) => (
        <FormikForm>
          <SimpleGrid
            columns={{ xl: "3", sm: "1" }}
            spacing={5}
            mx={5}
            w={{ sm: "90%" }}
          >
            <Field name="companyName" validate={validateCompanyName}>
              {({ field, form }) => (
                <FormControl
                  isInvalid={
                    form.errors.companyName && form.touched.companyName
                  }
                >
                  <Input
                    {...field}
                    borderBottomColor="grey"
                    borderBottomWidth="5px"
                    borderLeft="none"
                    borderRight="none"
                    borderTop="none"
                    type="text"
                    name="companyName"
                    placeholder="Company Name"
                  />
                  <FormErrorMessage>
                    {form.errors.companyName}
                  </FormErrorMessage>
                </FormControl>
              )}
            </Field>
            <Field name="ruc" validate={validateRucNumber}>
              {({ field, form }) => (
                <FormControl
                  isInvalid={form.errors.ruc && form.touched.ruc}
                >
                  <Input
                    {...field}
                    borderBottomColor="grey"
                    borderBottomWidth="5px"
                    borderLeft="none"
                    borderRight="none"
                    borderTop="none"
                    type="text"
                    name="ruc"
                    placeholder="RUC Number"
                  />
                  <FormErrorMessage>{form.errors.ruc}</FormErrorMessage>
                </FormControl>
              )}
            </Field>
            <Field name="rucAgain" validate={validateRucNumber}>
              {({ field, form }) => (
                <FormControl
                  isInvalid={form.errors.ruc && form.touched.ruc}
                >
                  <Input
                    {...field}
                    borderBottomColor="grey"
                    borderBottomWidth="5px"
                    borderLeft="none"
                    borderRight="none"
                    borderTop="none"
                    type="text"
                    name="rucAgain"
                    placeholder="RUC Number Again"
                  />
                  <FormErrorMessage>{form.errors.ruc}</FormErrorMessage>
                </FormControl>
              )}
            </Field>
          </SimpleGrid>
          <SimpleGrid
            columns={{ xl: "2", sm: "1" }}
            mt={10}
            mx={5}
            w={{ sm: "90%" }}
            spacing={10}
          >
            <Field name="password" validate={validatePassword}>
              {({ field, form }) => (
                <FormControl
                  isInvalid={form.errors.password && form.touched.password}
                >
                  <Input
                    {...field}
                    border="none"
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                  />
                  <FormErrorMessage>
                    {form.errors.password}
                  </FormErrorMessage>
                </FormControl>
              )}
            </Field>
            <Field name="passwordAgain" validate={validatePassword}>
              {({ field, form }) => (
                <FormControl
                  isInvalid={form.errors.password && form.touched.password}
                >
                  <Input
                    {...field}
                    border="none"
                    type="password"
                    name="passwordAgain"
                    placeholder="Confirm Password"
                  />
                  <FormErrorMessage>
                    {form.errors.password}
                  </FormErrorMessage>
                </FormControl>
              )}
            </Field>
          </SimpleGrid>
          <SimpleGrid
            columns={{ xl: "2", sm: "1" }}
            w={{ sm: "90%" }}
            mt={10}
            mx={5}
            spacing={10}
          >
            <Field name="email" validate={validateEmail}>
              {({ field, form }) => (
                <FormControl
                  isInvalid={form.errors.email && form.touched.email}
                >
                  <Input
                    {...field}
                    border="none"
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                  />
                  <FormErrorMessage>{form.errors.email}</FormErrorMessage>
                </FormControl>
              )}
            </Field>
            <Field name="phone" validate={validateEmail}>
              {() => (
                <Input
                  border="none"
                  type="tel"
                  name="phone"
                  placeholder="Phone Number"
                />
              )}
            </Field>
          </SimpleGrid>

          <SimpleGrid columns={1} mt={10} mx={5} display="flex">
            <FormLabel>Gas Station(s): </FormLabel>
            <ReactTags
              inputFieldPosition="top"
              tags={tag.tags}
              suggestions={tag.suggestions}
              handleDelete={tagDelete}
              handleAddition={tagAdd}
              handleDrag={tagDrag}
              delimiters={delimiters}
              placeholder=""
              classNames={{
                tagInputField: "chakra-input css-1c6j008",
              }}
            />
          </SimpleGrid>

          <Flex mt={10} mx={5} w="50vh">
            <FormLabel mt={2}>Vehicle(s): </FormLabel>
            <Input
              type="text"
              size="md"
              onKeyPress={onPlateKeyPress}
              onChange={onChangePlate}
              value={vehiclePlate}
              name="vehiclePlate"
            ></Input>
            <Box display="grid">
              {plate.plates && Array.isArray(plate.plates)
                ? plate.plates.map((plat) => (
                    <Box display={width < 768 ? "block" : ""}>
                      <VehicleTag plate={plat} onDelete={onDeletePlate} />
                    </Box>
                  ))
                : ""}
            </Box>
          </Flex>

          <Flex mt={10} mx={5} w="50vh">
            <FormLabel mt={2}>Drivers: </FormLabel>
            <InputGroup onKeyPress={onDriverKeyPress}>
              <Input
                type="text"
                size="md"
                onChange={onChangeDriver}
                value={driverName}
                name="driverName"
              ></Input>
              <Input
                type="text"
                size="md"
                onChange={onChangeDriver}
                value={driverNumber}
                name="driverNumber"
              ></Input>
            </InputGroup>
          </Flex>
          <Box display="block" w="50vh" mt={5} ms={-2}>
            <Box display="grid">
              {driver.drivers && Array.isArray(driver.drivers)
                ? driver.drivers.map((driv) => (
                    <Box display={width < 768 ? "block" : ""} w="100%">
                      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
                        <DriverTag
                          driver={driv}
                          onDeleteDriver={onDeleteDriver}
                        />
                      </Box>
                    </Box>
                  ))
                : ""}
            </Box>
          </Box>

          <Box mt={10}>
            <Checkbox> I agree with terms and conditions</Checkbox>
          </Box>

          <Box mt={10}>
            <Button bg="#242348" color="white" type="submit">
              Sign Up
            </Button>

            <Link as={ReachLink} to="/login" display="block" mt={10}>
              Already have an account? Sign In
            </Link>
          </Box>
        </FormikForm>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

This is what I have so far in the form. Can anyone shed some light as to why my form is not submitting?